# Get table names .net business connector [AXAPTA]

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, business-connector

I would like to know if there is a way to get all table names from AOT by using .NET business connector without calling X++ code in AX?

According to MSDN, we have to provide table name. [[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc197126%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)]

```
Axapta ax;
AxaptaRecord axRecord;
using (axRecord = ax.CreateAxaptaRecord(tableName));
{
    // Perform actions
}
```

Axapta Class has only "GetRecordCount" but nothing to get record names.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list from AX [then access that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495638/return-a-list-to-net-business-connector/14496827#14496827)!

Or you could use the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa600103%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) class:

```
static void findTables(Args _args)
{
    Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
    TableId tableId;
    TableName tableName;
    for (tableId = dictionary.tableNext(0); tableId; tableId = dictionary.tableNext(tableId))
    {
        tableName = dictionary.tableName(tableId);
        info(strfmt('%1 - %2', tableId, tableName));        
    }
}
```

This is X++ code but the translation to C# is trivial.

Comment: So, can I not access table meta-data from .NET Business connector? Is it a must to have methods in AX for getting details like table names, columns inside tables?

Comment: You can, as I said: This is X++ code but the translation to C# is trivial.

Comment: I didnt get it. You can call the above X++ code in C# via Axapta.CallStaticClassMethod. How can you transform x++ to C#??? I looking to access this meta-data without any code written inside Dynamics AX.

Comment: I want to achieve the above using Axapta class in the business connector without calling any method in axapta. I guess its not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what the previous answer states, it is possible to return a list of table names with the .Net Business Connector.

This method uses the ExecuteStmt method on AxaptaRecord to execute X++ code dynamically.

From your client code

```
Axapta ax = new Axapta();
using (AxaptaRecord r = ax.CreateAxaptaRecord("SQLDICTIONARY")) 
{
    r.ExecuteStmt("SELECT NAME, TABID FROM %1 WHERE %1.NAME LIKE 'CUST*' && %1.FIELDID == 0");

    while (r.Found) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine((string)r.get_Field("NAME"));
    }
}
```

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa594213(v=ax.50).aspx
http://www.stoneridgesoftware.com/using-like-in-x/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa848113.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Axapta ax = new Axapta();
ax.LogonAs(name, domain, null,null,null,null,null);
AxaptaObject dictable = ax.CreateAxaptaObject("Dictionary");
int index = (int)dictable.Call("tableNext", 0);

while(index > 0) {
    AxaptaObject table = (AxaptaObject)dictable.Call("tableObject", index);
    string tableName = (string)table.Call("name");
    int next = (int)dictable.Call("tableNext", index);
    if (next <= index) 
        break;
    index = next;
}
```